# How to initialize an array from a method

Tags: java, arrays

I have written a method to return an array of random integers. How do I go about initializing the array in my main method by calling the method.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    new int[] rdmArray = randomArray(100);

}

public int[] randomArray (int size) {
    Random rdm = new Random();
    int[] array = new int[size];
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        array[i] = rdm.nextInt();

    return array;
```

Comment: just `int[] rdmArray = randomArray(100);`

Comment: Remove new from `new int[] rdmArray = randomArray(100);`

Comment: int[] rdmArray = randomArray(100);

Comment: Furthermore, a non-static method cannot be called from within a static method without an instance.

Comment: Also you should either make your randomArray method static or call it with class object.

Comment: You could also use streams for this: `int[] rdmArray = new Random().ints().limit(100).toArray();`

Answer (score 1):

Do this,

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

   int[] rdmArray = randomArray(100);

}

public static int[] randomArray (int size) {
   Random rdm = new Random();
   int[] array = new int[size];
   for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    array[i] = rdm.nextInt();

  return array;
}
```

or this,

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

  YourClassName obj = new YourClassName();
  int[] rdmArray = obj.randomArray(100);

}

public int[] randomArray (int size) {
   Random rdm = new Random();
   int[] array = new int[size];
   for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    array[i] = rdm.nextInt();

  return array;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are using the wrong syntax to instantiate an Object and you are in the wrong context since the main method is `static` while the method `randomArray` is not.

Change it to

```
int[] rdmArray = randomArray(100);
```

and declare `randomArray(int size)` as static.